# Magento how to create shipping label dynamically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to `generate shipping label dynamically` once order is placed.

I have **fedex shipping method** configured and works fine for setting the order status to shipping once order placed and from admin am able to create shipping label manually and it is giving pdf when i click Print Shipping label after shipping label created.

Now this process needs to be automated - *how i can able to create hipping labels dynamically?* Is there any observer or class overwriting examples. Please help me to  create shipping label dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you want an official Shipping Label with bar code you will need to purchase an extension like this one:
  http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-extension.html

The extension has a cahcing feature where it will store all of your shipping labels so you can easily re-print them at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

As know, you can print shipping label only when have invoice. We want let you know extension can help you solved. Or you can check our code for create

Magento 1: http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/shipping/print-shipping-label.html

Magento 2: http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/shipping/print-shipping-label-for-magento-2.html

or use code

Below is the controller.

```
public function printShippingLabelAction(){
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
        if (!empty($invoicesIds)) {
            $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $ids))
                ->load();
            if (!isset($pdf)){
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_order')->getPdf($orders );
            } else {
                $pages = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_order')->getPdf($orders );
                $pdf->pages = array_merge ($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
            }

            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('order'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

Create model

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
    {

        public function getPdf($orders = array())
        {
            $this->_beforeGetPdf();
            $this->_initRenderer('order');

            $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
            $this->_setPdf($pdf);
            $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
            $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

            foreach ($orders as $order) {

                $page  = $this->newPage();


                $this->insertLogo($page, $order->getStore());

                $this->insertAddress($page, $order->getStore());

                $this->insertOrder(
                    $page,
                    $order,
                    Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId())
                );

                $this->insertDocumentNumber(
                    $page,
                    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order # ') . $order->getIncrementId()
                );

                $this->_drawHeader($page);

                foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                    $page = end($pdf->pages);
                }

                $this->insertTotals($page, $order);
                if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                    Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
                }
            }
            $this->_afterGetPdf();
            return $pdf;
        }}
```